# How to check if player wins in tic-tac-toe game?

Tags: c#, winforms, tic-tac-toe

**Hi,
Im working on Visual Studio Winforms and I'm trying to build tic-tac-toe.
I got stuck in the Check if player win method.
I have tried to do that in activated. little example:**

```
    private void StartForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((_pcb1.Image == imagecircle) && (_pcb2.Image == imagecircle) && (_pcb3.Image == imagecircle))
        {
           MessageBox.Show("You Win!");

        }
        if ((_pcb4.Image == imagecircle) && (_pcb5.Image == imagecircle) && (_pcb6.Image == imagecircle))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Win!");
        }

        if ((_pcb7.Image == imagecircle) && (_pcb8.Image == imagecircle) && (_pcb9.Image == imagecircle))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Win!");
        }
    }
```

**(I know that there are more situations to win).
It's never get into the method, I trying to find a method that active always when the form is open. please help :)**

Comment: Your approach is wrong on so many levels! You need to keep a model object that represents the current state of the board. Whenever you place an image on the board, mark the model with the corresponding item (cross or circle). Make a method in a model class to determine who won (if anyone). Call this method after each move to decide what to do next (display a message box or wait for the next move).

Comment: You don't want to hook the `Activated`. Instead, check for a win in the same place that you set an X or an O when the player clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check player's victory after each move of that player. I assume, that your players make their moves by clicking on "Make a Move" button or clicking on the game field. Also I assume, that you have `Click` event of your button or game field. So you should paste your check code in `Click` event of your button or game field.

Comment: @user3393134 If this answer helped you, please, accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will extend to whatever game size:

```
public class Level
{
    private readonly Team[,] _game;

    public Level(int extent)
    {
        _game = new Team[extent, extent];
    }

    public bool HasWon(Team team)
    {
        var yMax = GetYMax();
        var xMax = GetXMax();
        var won = false;

        // check horizontally
        for (var y = 0; y < yMax; y++)
        {
            won = false;
            for (var x = 0; x < xMax; x++)
                won |= _game[y, x] == team;

            if (won) return true;
        }

        // TODO check vertically

        // TODO check diagonally

        return won;
    }

    public void SetTile(Team team, int x, int y)
    {
        var xMax = GetXMax();
        var yMax = GetYMax();

        if ((x < 0) || (x > xMax))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("x");

        if ((y < 0) || (y > yMax))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("y");

        _game[y, x] = team;
    }

    private int GetXMax()
    {
        var xMax = _game.GetUpperBound(1);
        return xMax;
    }

    private int GetYMax()
    {
        var yMax = _game.GetUpperBound(0);
        return yMax;
    }
}

public enum Team
{
    Red,
    Blue
}
```

**Things for you to do:**

- implement logic for checking if a team has won vertically or diagonally
- implement your game using this class, drawing pictures according the array `_game` (make it available publicly)
- study the `|` OR operator to understand how it's used in here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx
- further debug the code (I haven't :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find some method that is constantly called, so as to check whether the players have won, you can just create a `Timer` that runs every 1 millisecond. Then the event handler for `Timer.Tick` would be such a method.

However, you shouldn't find such a method to check for winning/losing. It's a waste of resources to check for that every 1 millisecond.

Think, what action can affect the result of a game of tic tac toe? It's of course when either player places something (X or O) on the board! *That* is when you need to check whether someone has won. Also, if the thing placed is a X, you don't need to check whether the player who is playing O has won, because that's simply impossible!

Also, checking whether the image in a picture box is equal to the X or O image is really "non abstract" code. Try to put these things into a model by abstraction.